# How to find `record` from ec2 instance id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-route53

Using ansible, is there any way to find subdomain bound to instance? Subdomains are created in amazon route53.

The reason for this is that I have playbook which is deleting all instances with certain tags. However, the `A` records remain and I would like also to delete them.

So how can I find and delete instance's corresponding A record?

Comment: What version of ansible are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.

If the control host or any other instance has AWS CLI installed, you can run ansible shell command **aws route53 list-resource-record-sets** and loop through the output to find the matching record.

Ansible 2.0beta has **route53_facts** module. Fetch the record sets by setting **query: record_sets** and loop through the output to find the matching record.

Comment: Is it feasible to use `uri` module to do `listResourceRecordSets` through REST API or stock modules will not support all the signing stuff?

Comment: I do not think uri knows anything about signing stuff. You have to do it manually and add it to the header. If you know how to do it, you can give it a try. I will write a shell script that accepts an argument and returns a record. Call that script from ansible to get the record. The shell script can use AWS CLI or REST API to query and return the record.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've terminated the EC2 instance, it's too late to associate it with a Route 53 record. This is because the public IP address information is lost once the instance is terminated.

So you'll need to do it before termination, or as part of the termination process.

1. Before the EC2 instance is terminated, see what it's public IP address is.
2. Remove the Route 53 A record that corresponds with that IP address.
3. Terminate the EC2 instance.

Comment: That's the point. #2 - How to find which record corresponding to my instance? Giving only IP address to `route53` module yields to error, that `record` element is missing. In `record` element subdomain should be specified. All I have is instance facts, but not subdomain which I can give to `record` field.

Comment: You'll have to scan the route 53 records to find one that matches the IP address. The instance does not know the subdomain.

Comment: That's the question - how to scan / with ansible /?